# TYPO3 tx_news more-link only showing default translation

Tags: typo3, tx-news

In TYPO3 tx_news i have the more-link, but it only shows the default translation in every language.

My default language is Danish.

In items.html I have this:

```
<f:translate key="more-link"/>
```

In my TypoScript I have this

```
plugin.tx_news._LOCAL_LANG.de.more-link = mehr
plugin.tx_news._LOCAL_LANG.en.more-link = read more
plugin.tx_news._LOCAL_LANG.default.more-link = læs mere
```

I can also see these values in TypoScript Object Browser.
But on the English and the German page the link text is "læs mere".

What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you clear all caches (preferably from the install tool) after changing the localization?

Comment: Please use default for `en` only and use the correct locale for danish

Answer (score -1):

Check your language settings in your `setup` TypoScript.

You should set for english:

```
config.language = en
```

and for german:

```
config.language = de
```

> This configures the system “language key” to be used for the language.
>   This is used to select labels from XLF files. Setting this should make
>   frontend plugins respond by showing labels from the correct language
>   (requires installation of the corresponding translations).

Actually with the settings above you change in TypoScript the default values from a language file. As you see you are using there the `de` and `en` properties. This settings should be set correctly in your config also to enable TYPO3 to match them.

Documentation is [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FrontendLocalizationGuide/BasicSetupOfALocalizedWebsite/TyposcriptConfiguration/Index.html).